# How to decide what to mock in Java Unit Tests?

Tags: unit-testing, mocking, mockito

I am trying to write a Unit Tests to a legacy code using Mockito.

But I am not able to understand how do I mock it. Can some please help.

The real problem I am facing is actually I am not able to decide how to make a decision on what exactly is to be mocked? Below is the code. I have looked at numerous videos on YouTube and read many Mockito Tutorials but all of them seem to be guiding mostly about how to use the Mockito Framework.

The basic idea of what to Mock is still unclear. Please guide if you have a better source. I do understand that the code showed below does not really showcase the best coding practice.

```
    public class DataFacade {

    public boolean checkUserPresent(String userId){
        return getSomeDao.checkUserPresent(userId);
    }


    private SomeDao getSomeDao() {
        DataSource dataSource = MyDataSourceFactory.getMySQLDataSource();
        SomeDao someDao = new SomeDao(dataSource);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, a **Unit**test, as the name implies, tests a unit. You should mock anything that isn't part of that unit, especially external dependencies. For example, a DAO is normally a good example for something that will be mocked in tests where the class under tests uses it, because otherwise you would really have actual data access in your test, making it slower and more prone to failure because of external reasons (for example, if your dao connects to a `Datasource`, that `Datasource`'s target (for example, the database) may be down, failing your test even if the unit you wanted to test is actually perfectly fine). Mocking the DAO allows you to test things independently.

Of course, your code is bad. Why? You are creating everything in your method by calling some static factory method. I suggest instead using dependency injection to inject the DAO into your facade, for example...

```
public DataFacade(SomeDao someDao) {
   this.someDao = someDao;
}
```

This way, when instantiating your DataFacade, you can give it a dao, which means, in your test you can give it a mock, for example...

```
@Test
public void testSomething() {
    SomeDao someDaoMock = Mockito.mock(SomeDao.class);
    DataFacade toTest = new DataFacade(someDaoMock);

    ...now you can prepare your mock to do something and then call the DataFace method
}
```

Dependency injection frameworks like Spring, Google Guice, etc. can make this even easier to manage, but the first step is to stop your classes from creating their own dependencies, but let the dependencies be given to them from the outside, which makes the whole thing a lot better.

Comment: Which is the best book/source to learn Unit Testing concepts and  Mockito?

Comment: Hard to say, since I never actually started out with one source, but instead I simply did things horribly wrong and slowly learned to do them wrong less horribly with various sources, including StackOverflow, so I cannot suggest a good book for that specifically.

Answer (score 0):

You should "mock" the inner objects that you use in your methods.

For example if you write unit tests for `DataFacade->checkUserPresent`, you should mock the `getSomeDao` field.

You have a lot of ways to do it, but basically you can make `getSomeDao` to be public field, or get it from the constructor. In your test class, override this field with mocked object.
After you invoke `DataFacade->checkUserPresent` method, assert that checkUserPresent() is called.

For exmaple if you have this class:

```
public class StudentsStore
{
   private DbReader _db;

   public StudentsStore(DbReader db)
   {
      _db = db;
   }

   public bool HasStudents()
   {
      var studentsCount = _db.GetStudentsCount();
      if (studentsCount > 0)
         return true;
      else
         return false;
   }
}
```

And in your test method:

```
var mockedDb = mock(DbReader.class);
when(mockedDb.GetStudentsCount()).thenReturn(1);

var store = new StudentsSture(mockedDb);

assertEquals(true,store.HasStudents());
```